# Unable to find ansible modules

Tags: ansible

I am new to ansible. I want to learn ansible by following ansible doc.

I know one module is there named as handlers in ansible but I cannot find it in ansible list of modules.

Is there any other place where they are maintaining all modules.Its confusing that the module is not available in ansible module list but people are still using.

Thanks in advance

Comment: This is the [complete list](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/list_of_all_modules.html)

Comment: I could't find handler module here.

Comment: Handlers are not modules but tasks that you can give a name and "call" them when another task has been performed. You can use the same modules in handlers as in normal tasks. See this section http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_intro.html#handlers-running-operations-on-change

Answer (score -1):

As per the docs:

> **Handlers**
>   Handlers are just like regular tasks in an Ansible playbook (see Tasks) but are only run if the Task contains a notify directive and also indicates that it changed something. For example, if a config file is changed, then the task referencing the config file templating operation may notify a service restart handler. This means services can be bounced only if they need to be restarted. Handlers can be used for things other than service restarts, but service restarts are the most common usage.

http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/glossary.html

Generally, handlers are used to change or manage the status of a service. For example:

```
  handlers:
- name: Restart Nginx
  become: true
  service:
    name: nginx
    state: restarted
```

You can read more [here](https://knpuniversity.com/screencast/ansible/handlers).

You should read more about [tasks](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_intro.html) or refer to the glossary.